# Detecting a long Press on Item of RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview, ontouchlistener

i am using OnTouchListener in Item of RecyclerView.i detect Long press and MotionEvent.ACTION_UP.

```
  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
 imageLoader.displayImage("file:///" + imagesData.imagePath, holder.binding.items)
        holder.binding.items.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener{
            override fun onTouch(p0: View?, p1: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
                if (p1 != null) {
                    if (p1.action==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000)

                    }
                    if (p1.action==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
                    }
                }
                return true
            }

        })
}
```

But i face a issue when i scroll RecyclerView. My handler Run  after 1 second during Scrooling.
How i Can Handle this.

Comment: Why are  you not using the onLongClickListener ?

Comment: beacuse i do some action when finger up from longClick